# Date filter not working in Power BI DAX with Calculate and SUM

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to filter date column using Power BI Dax. When i add the date column it becomes blank. But without Date filter Query is perfectly working. Date is in m/dd/yyy format and n the excel (source file)  it is in 'short date' format.

```
Hours = 
CALCULATE(
SUM('downtimetracker'[Duration (hours)]),
all('downtimetracker'),
'downtimetracker'[Date] in {3/10/2022},
'downtimetracker'[Instance] in {"USA"},
'downtimetracker'[Type] in {"Unplanned"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the date into a string using `FORMAT()` and compare with a list of strings:

```
Hours = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('downtimetracker'[Duration (hours)]),
    all('downtimetracker'),
    FORMAT('downtimetracker'[Date], "mm/dd/yyyy") in {"03/10/2022"},
    'downtimetracker'[Instance] in {"USA"},
    'downtimetracker'[Type] in {"Unplanned"}
)
```